# Accidentally Used Latex Paint instead of Oil Primer

Tags: paint, sealer

I grabbed the wrong bucket and painted the exterior window sashes with the latex paint thinking it was the oil primer. Should I paint it with another coat of latex and then wait and see or is there a sealer primer I can put over it before I have problems?